# Uplaoded Image but with 0 KB size

Tags: iis, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 but I encountered a weird problem!
the problem is any uploaded image the size of it is 0KB
when I restart the IIS and trying again will upload it without any problem but after that, the problem returns back.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48866710/file-upload-in-asp-net-core-2-0-issue-creating-0-byte-image) by making my code async but with no luck

I changed my system file to be accessible by my Application pool user but with no luck

Here is my code :

```
public Document shareWithUsers([FromForm] CreateDocumentDto documentDto)
        {
            List<CreateUserType1DocumentsDto> listOfCreateUserType1Documents = new List<CreateUserType1DocumentsDto>();
            List<CreateHDDocumentsDto> listOfCreateHDDocuments = new List<CreateHDDocumentsDto>();

            if (documentDto.listOfUserType1Documents != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in documentDto.listOfUserType1Documents)
                {
                    listOfCreateUserType1Documents.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateUserType1DocumentsDto>(item));
                }
            }
            else if (documentDto.listOfHDDocuments != null)
            {


                foreach (var item in documentDto.listOfHDDocuments)
                {
                    listOfCreateHDDocuments.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateHDDocumentsDto>(item));
                }
            }



            if (documentDto.sharedText == null)
            {


                if (documentDto.document != null) //that mean user upload  file
                {
                    if (documentDto.document.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var UploadedFilesPath = Path.Combine(hosting.WebRootPath/*wwwroot path*/, "UploadedFiles"  /*folder name in wwwroot path*/);
                        var filePath = Path.Combine(UploadedFilesPath, documentDto.document.FileName);
                      
                        //documentDto.docUrl = filePath;

                        var documentObject = new Document();


                        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            documentDto.document.CopyToAsync(stream);// Use stream
                        }

                        





                        if (documentDto.listOfUserType1Documents != null)
                            {
                                documentObject.listOfUserType1Documents = ObjectMapper.Map<List<UserType1Documents>>(listOfCreateUserType1Documents);
                            }
                            else if (documentDto.listOfHDDocuments != null)
                            {
                                documentObject.listOfHDDocuments = ObjectMapper.Map<List<HDDocuments>>(listOfCreateHDDocuments);
                            }

                            documentObject.docTtitle = documentDto.docTtitle;
                            documentObject.docName = documentDto.docName;
                            documentObject.docUrl = filePath;



                        return  _repository.Insert(documentObject);


                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {     //that mean user upload  text 
                var documentObject = new Document();
                if (documentDto.listOfUserType1Documents != null)
                {
                    documentObject.listOfUserType1Documents = ObjectMapper.Map<List<UserType1Documents>>(listOfCreateUserType1Documents);
                }
                else if (documentDto.listOfHDDocuments != null)
                {
                    documentObject.listOfHDDocuments = ObjectMapper.Map<List<HDDocuments>>(listOfCreateHDDocuments);
                }
                documentObject.sharedText = documentDto.sharedText;
                return _repository.Insert(documentObject);

            }


            return null;



        }
```

Comment: `documentDto.document.CopyToAsync(stream)` - either "await" it or change to non-async (`CopyTo()`). Not sure this solve your problem, but it really should not work without it.

Comment: @Dmitry thank you it works , My problem was changed the Insert to InsertAsync with await without adding await before CopyToAsync ! anyway if you want you can put your your comment as an answer to give you the points

Comment: Not-awaiting XxxAsync is very not recommended :) If your code "works" without awaiting CopyToAsync - I have bad news for you, your code will fail at some random point in future. Also, changing `Insert` to `await InsertAsync` does not seem like real problem-solver... I think your code works "by accident" and you should test it more to see it, sorry.

Comment: my code works only if I change both of them (CopyTo and Insert ) to Async with await (await CopyToAsync and await InsertAsync ) and that what I meant in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code works only if I change both of them (CopyTo and Insert ) to Async with await

await CopyToAsync()

await InsertAsync()